# Indenting an item between number and text

Tags: indentation, itemize

There are already many similar questions, unfortunately mine is slightly different. I'd like to indent *between* the item marker (number, bullet...) and the text. This is easily done with e.g. \item \hspace{3mm}...only that if the line breaks, it doesn't align with the rest above it. (I do have enumitem loaded, if that helps. For normal text \adjustwidth should do the trick, right?) Abusing code formatting:

```
Not so good
* bla
*    blablablablablablablabla
  blablablablablablablablabla
Better
* bla
*    blablablablablablablabla
     blablablablablablablabla
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having `enumitem` loaded you can nest `itemize`-environments to achieve what you're after. The documentation is still helpful (starting on page 6 you'll find section [3.2 Horizontal spacing of labels](https://ctan.net/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf)).

What follows is a highly **edited** example for your convenience:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\section*{Enumitem}

\begin{enumerate}[%
    parsep=.5\parskip,
    labelsep=1em,
]
    \item First item
    \begin{enumerate}[%
        label=$\arabic*$,
        leftmargin=*,
        labelindent=-1.5em,
        labelsep=2em,
    ]
        \item[2.] First \emph{nested} item
        \item[3.] Second \emph{nested} item
    \end{enumerate}
    \item[4.] Second item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: enumitem nested enumerate]

Comment: But that increases itemindent for *all* items on the list. It must be something inserted after the item itself (like the \hspace example). And it seems the enumitem paragraph you mentioned only covers the former case.

Comment: @HaukeReddmann, I must have misread your question. Did you state that you needed just one item indented?

Comment: Well, ideally it shall look like a normal nested itemize env...just with aligned numbers in front, as in my bla example (Luckily, I need it only once, so it wouldn't be that bad if it doesn't work and I could cheat myself to the wanted result with some line breaks and artificial indenting.)

Comment: @HaukeReddmann, I see. I had to play with the options for a while. I think my edit comes close to what you need.

Comment: @HaukeReddmann, I have now edited the answer to include the `enumerate`-environment.

Comment: Looks good. So in essence I nest enum envs (and now I only have to see the numbers come out right).

Comment: @HaukeReddmann, I have to confess, my knowledge of the `enumitem`-package is limited. I cannot give you a better answer, I'm afraid. Is there nothing in the documentation about this?